# How to split the results of a php xpath query

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to build a page that when a website URL is added to the input my php will scrape that page and display the input names for each form on that page.

I have successfully accomplished this, however im trying to split the results to make them easier to read if there are multiple forms on a page.

```
<form action="" method="post">
                <label style="color:#000000; font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; display:block;">Website URL:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="website-url-value" id="website-url-value" style="border:1px solid #000;" />
                <div style="display:block; clear:both; margin-bottom:20px;"></div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Find forms" />
            </form>

        <?php
            $html = file_get_contents($_POST['website-url-value']);
            $website_doc = new DOMDocument();
            libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors
            if(!empty($html)){ //if any html is actually returned
                $website_doc->loadHTML($html);
                libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for bad html

                $website_xpath = new DOMXPath($website_doc);
                $form_total = 1; // initial form counter
                //get all the form fields
                $full_forms = $website_xpath->query('
                    //form
                '); // find forms on page
                $full_inputs = $website_xpath->query('
                    //input[@type="text"]|
                    //input[@type="radio"]|
                    //input[@type="checkbox"]|
                    //input[@type="tel"]|
                    //input[@type="email"]|
                    //input[@type="date"]|
                    //input[@type="number"]|
                    //input[@type="time"]|
                    //textarea|
                    //select'
                ); // find form fields with these types
                if($full_inputs->length > 0){
                    foreach($full_inputs as $single_input){
                        echo $single_input->getAttribute('name') . '<br />'; // show each field followed by new line
                    }
                }
                if($full_forms->length > 0){
                    foreach($full_forms as $single_form){
                        echo '<strong>' . $single_form->nodeName . " " . $form_total++ . '</strong><br />'; // show form plus count
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
```

I expect the result to look like:
Form 1:
FirstName
LastName
Email

Form 2:
FirstName
LastName
Phone

But currently the results i am getting is as below:

FirstName
LastName
Email
FirstName
LastName
Phone
Form 1:
Form 2:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is getting all input from the html documents, what you need to do is get 1 form at a time and get their relevant inputs.

One more thing is xpath returns nodelist as a result, but we can use the nodelist and convert it into xpath again to query further. For that you can use `descendant` parameter and pass nodelist as 2nd parameter.

Try this :

```
if(!empty($html)) {
    $website_doc = new DOMDocument();

    libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors

    $website_doc->loadHTML($html);

    libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for bad html

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($website_doc);

    $forms = $xpath->query("//form");

    foreach($forms as $key => $form) {
        $inputs = $xpath->query('descendant::
            input[@type="text"]|
            input[@type="radio"]|
            input[@type="checkbox"]|
            input[@type="tel"]|
            input[@type="email"]|
            input[@type="date"]|
            input[@type="number"]|
            input[@type="time"]|
            textarea|
            select', $form);

        echo "Form ".($key+1)." <br>";

        foreach ($inputs as $input) {
            echo $input->getAttribute('name') . '<br />';
        }

        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it now splits the results, but instead of showing all forms on the page, it is now showing only the first form, but repeating for each form count.


like so:
Form1:
FirstName
LastName
Email


Form 2:
FirstName
LastName
Email

Comment: You are sying it is showing 1st form, but later you show its showing `form1: ... form2: ...` that means its getting more than 1 form, it should list all form in the html. Post your all form of html in question, so it can be checked

Comment: Sorry, you are correct! It is showing fields from both forms, after looking closer it seems it only showing fields with type text.

Comment: I managed to get this to work by adding descendant:: to the beginning of each input type line. Thanks for your help, it got me to where i need to be!!!

Comment: Good to hear it worked out for you, It should work without adding descendant to each item, but well, enjoy